# Placing HTML inside rails links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I want to turn the following list-group-item into a link_to, i.e. link_to (post.title, post_path) but the following link contains a h4 and p element. How would I incorporate this? I though of just turning it all into a string, but then would you not have a problem with escaping html?

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= post.title %></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= post.content %></p>
  </a>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= post.title %></h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= post.content %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To learn more about `link_to`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Thanks, I just added :class=>"list-group-item" in the link_to. I'm seeing you everywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

`link_to` accepts a block

```
<%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= post.title %></h4>
 <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= post.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

If you want any other options you'd put them on the end but before the block

```
<%= link_to post_path(post), remote: true do %>
```